# Convert instance variables and their values into a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, instance-variables

I have a class `MyClass` with instance variables `@id` and `@color`:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :id, :color
end
```

I created an object by:

```
d = MyClass.new
d.id = 2
d.color = 'red'
d #=> #<MyClass:0x00000005fb52c0 @id=2, @color="red">
```

I would like to get a hash containing the instance variables and their values:

```
d.to_hash #=> { id: 2, color: 'red'}
```

What's the best way to implement such method?

Comment: What is the point of showing the expression `d[1]`?

Comment: to show you this output I got in console...  => #<MyClass:0x00000005fb52c0 @id=2, @color="red">, I created multiple objects x.times Class.new

Comment: @sawa may be `d` is a collection of objects.. and OP did `d[1]` to show one of them.. how they do look like... My guess.. :)

Comment: yup, It looks confusing at this point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Klass
  def initialize
    @a = 2
    @b = 2
  end

  # define your own methods
  def attributes
    instance_variables.map do |var| 
      [var[1..-1].to_sym, instance_variable_get(var)]
    end.to_h
  end
end

Klass.new.attributes # => {:a=>2, :b=>2}
```

Comment: It's cool to write own methods but I expected ruby to have ready method for it  :)

Comment: @Ann Ruby left it as an exercise for us.. :p

Comment: @Ann in case you are going to use Rails, theres an [`attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) methods

Answer (score 3):

A `Struct` is a way of constructing a Class with a few extra's built in: an easy way of initializing and a `to_h` method.

```
MyClass = Struct.new(:id, :color)
d = MyClass.new(2, "red")
p d.to_h # => {:id=>2, :color=>"red"}

# MyClass is a Class:
p d.class # => MyClass
```